# Search the real next occurrence of pattern in vim

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the text "testestestest"

If I search for "test", vim will only match the 1st & 3rd "test"

I wonder if there's an option to change this default behavior? It's not practical, but I'm just curious

Match four "test" above

Comment: I think this question is not suitable for StackOverflow. But you can find solutions here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36229/how-to-overlap-searching-result.

Comment: @z11i wow, thank you, that's exactly what I want